# Page Metadata Keyword Empty

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

There's a metadata schema linked with the page and we try to get from the View the value of the keyword associated to this page. However the information is empty. We are using Java DXA 2.0.1.

We have mapped in our customPageModel

```
public class PublicPagesPageModel extends DefaultPageModel {
     @SemanticProperty(propertyName = "p:sitemapKeyword")
     private KeywordModel sitemapKw;
```

However when accessing the keyword in the jsp page, the value is empty

```
${pageModel.sitemapKw.key}
```

Comment: Is that keyword category published?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the issue was that in the Tridion schema this field was defined as multivalue.

Comment: Good that you found the problem/solution yourself.  However, if all is well, there should not be a problem with mapping a multi-valued CM field to a non-list property; it should just use the first value (and ignore any additional values).